# Packaging slip and shipping modules

Tags: expresso-store, shipping

Does any of the shipping modules provide a feature to print the package slip?
This is not really clear when browsing through the documentation and feature overview on the website.

Kind reagards,
Diederik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FedEx, UPS, USPS add-ons don't actually register the package with the provider but just calculate a possible rate. Therefore you would not be able to create a shipping label out of the box.

If you want to create a slip to include in the box to list the content you can either use the the built in PDF from the CP or create a template with the Orders tag pair.